# C++ primer 5 edition: passing a temporary shared_ptr to function

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, move-semantics, pass-by-value, copy-elision

On C++ primer 5 edition. chapter 12 Dynamic Memory:

> Consider the following function that operates on a shared_ptr:
>
> ```
> // ptr is created and initialized when process is called
> void process(shared_ptr<int> ptr)
> {
> // use ptr
> }   // ptr goes out of scope and is destroyed
> ```
>
> The parameter to process is passed by value, so the argument to process is copied into ptr. Copying a shared_ptr increments its reference count. Thus, inside process the count is at least 2. When process completes, the reference count of ptr is decremented but cannot go to zero. Therefore, when the local variable ptr is
>   destroyed, the memory to which ptr points will not be deleted.
>   The right way to use this function is to pass it a shared_ptr:
>
> ```
> shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42)); // reference count is 1
> process(p); // copying p increments its count; in process the reference count is 2
> int i = *p; // ok: reference count is 1
> ```

It is said that use_count in `process` is at least 2 thus when `ptr` goes out of scope it is destructed but the memory of object it manages is not freed?!

I think it is logically but consider this:

```
void process(shared_ptr<int> sp) {
    cout << sp.use_count() << endl;
    cout << *sp << endl;    
}

int main(){
    process(shared_ptr<int>(new int(57)));
}
```

The output:

> 1 and it is not 2 as he said?
>
> 57

- Does this mean some `std::move` was applied by the compiler as an optimization?
- Does he mean a memory-leak will happen in his example if no optimization was applied by the compiler to remove the Copy?

Comment: Likely, neither copy nor move was performed, but was [elided](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) entirely.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Yes I missed it! Copy-elision.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: So does it mean if running the same code without `copy-elision` optimization  then is that code yields a memory leak?

Comment: There can't be a memory leak no matter how many times it's copied because it will always be deleted when the last instance goes out of scope.

Comment: It is important to understand how `shared_ptr` works, but no part of that understanding requires one to keep track of `use_count`. That's `shared_ptr`'s job. `use_count` is available for you merely for convenience, perhaps logging and diagnostic purposes. But insofar as ordinary C++ code goes, it has no need to worry about `use_count`. That's `shared_ptr`'s job.

Comment: @PaulEvans: I aggree with you. As long as the last `shared_ptr` goes out of scope will handle the deletion of memory it manages. So the use_count inside `process` can be 2 or 1?

Comment: `use_count` of 1 just means you have the only instance of owning smart ptr for some resource; the definition of a ref counting (RC) owning is that the release function (by default, `delete`) is called with decrementing the RC produces a 0.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa A function accepting a *shared* owning smart ptr accepts the idea it doesn't have the sole owner, so why would the function care about the ref count?

Comment: Yes, because if the use count is 1 there's only one instance that will go out of scope at the end of `process` and a use count of 2 means there's a copy in `process` and the first instance will go out if scope at the end of `main`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Do you think this is a mistake in the book? "When process completes, the reference count of ptr is decremented but cannot go to zero. Therefore, when the local variable ptr is destroyed, the memory to which ptr points will not be deleted."

Comment: @curiousguy: Is it a mistake in the book? becauase the book says: the memory will not be deleted which points to memory leak?

Comment: @PaulEvans: Do you consider this a mistake in the book?

Comment: Why marked as Duplicate? But in fact it may show a mistake in the book? I am not to ask about Optimization like Copy-elision?

Comment: No, it's not a "mistake in the book". The book is simply not considering the case where the function parameter is a temporary object.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "// ptr is created and initialized when process is called" but I think this is a temporary he means.

Comment: Yes for sure it can be a mistake in the book. One thing to consider about shared_ptr s is they are really safe and the last one of them will manage the destruction of the underlying object. It doesn't matter how many shared_ptr manage your dynamic object or whether an optimization or not has been applied, use the in the right contest and it is guaranteed to you no memory leak.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Maybe the OP is quite correct because I've re-read the paragraph and the writer told: "ptr is created and initialized when process is called" which means a temporary shared_ptr is created upon `process` call. Also the writer told " Therefore, when the local variable ptr is destroyed, the memory to which ptr points will not be deleted. The right way to use this function is to pass it a shared_ptr:" which he means that Memory-leak also then he said: "The right way..." which means that the previous example is incorrect although it is correct.